# Custon DjangoTemplates for one app

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to use a third party app that did not use adequate django principles:

- templates \w hard coded urls instead of `{% url ... %}` syntax
- templates \w hard coded static files instead of `{% static ... %}` syntax
- makemigrations is left to the user/deployer
- all templates directly in templates folder, like `500.html`, `login.html`, etc
- interesting nested app-structure, where some apps are loaded depending on the configuration (i.e. advanced `settings.py` logic manipulating `INSTALLED_APPS`)

These make it hard to include the app in urls `/suburl/...`. I spent 15 minutes thinking this was rewritable, and a git PR would be a good idea, after realizing it might not be.

The most crucial problem, hard coded urls, is in the templates. Hence I want to copy the templates to my parent-project in a subfolder, fix them with generated urls, and redefine template-resolution for this particular app, but not for all apps.

This should keep my template-namespace relatively clean. Also, this way I avoid having to change all the view-functions to specify a better namespaced template. I don't want to get too involved in these, because these functions are massive.

Can I do this, define a customized `DjangoTemplates` for ONE specific app, but not the others?